# What speed is the SATA controller in a medio 2010 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, sata

I've got a Macbook Pro 15" 2,4GHz i5, medio 2010. I would like to upgrade to a solid state disk. But will I benefit from a disk with read/write speeds of 500 mb/s? Or what is the max speed that is supported by my SATA controller?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the speed of your SATA controller with the `System Information` application, by clicking `system report > hardware > Serial ATA`. Which in my case (a 15" 2.53GHz 2010 MBP) shows the following:

```
Intel 5 Series Chipset:

  Vendor:                   Intel
  Product:                  5 Series Chipset
  Link Speed:               3 Gigabit
  Negotiated Link Speed:    3 Gigabit
  Description:              AHCI Version 1.30 Supported
```

3 Gigabit means the maximum uncoded transfer rate is 2.4 Gbit/s or about 300MB/s (286MiB/s).

In conclusion: a 500MB/s disk is probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info. By my computer the Link speed is 3 Gigabit, but the negotiated link speed is 1,5 Gigabit. So, which number does affects my transfer rate? Sorry I'm quite a noob.

Comment: I believe that has to do with the disk currently in your Macbook. When you change the disk it should show the negotiated link speed as 3 Gigabit.